# I want to implement listview's longpress and then I want two things Delete and Update alert dialog. what should I do?

Tags: android

I am implementing listview's long press event and when I long press it then alert dialog should open and it should have two things update and delete. what should i do.please help me i have implemented this.

```
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {

            AlertDialog.Builder alert=new AlertDialog.Builder(ViewAllActivity.this);
            alert.setTitle("Which Action You Want to Perform...!!!");
            alert.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery);
            alert.setItems(ar, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(ViewAllActivity.this," Selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            return false;
        }
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) guide on AlertDialogs.
To fix your current issue, you need to add:

```
    alert.create().show();
```

before

```
    return false;
```

in your code.

Comment: Mate, did it helped you? If yes, please upvote answer and mark it as correct.